# Support for enlarged opening for new doors

Tags: framing, foundation, load-bearing, support

I’m considering enlarging an entry door (to the outside) from a single door to double doors (rough opening basically enlarged from 35” to 70”). It’s a two story brick house on field stone foundation (100+ years old). The foundation “appears” solid. No crumpling or cracks.

So my question is, should I consider if more support (concrete footing?)is needed for where the new king and jack studs will rest on the sill plate? I know the foundation is supporting it now, but with the enlarged open there will be more pressure on those two specific spots rather than spread out.

Comment: It is not the foundation that is the issue, A larger door, nor the studs around it,  will not be a problem.  The issue is the header, will you have enough height for a **properly sized header** to support the structure above the larger opening you will be creating.

Comment: Thanks for the question @AlaskaMan. I should have mentioned that. Yes, there is plenty of room above for a proper sized header (unless the proper size turns out to be more than 19”) They are 10’ ceilings.